# Acquiring a gun early without murdering innocent shopkeepers

Tags: spelunky

One thing that I have noticed is that acquiring some form of gun, be it a pistol or shotgun, makes the early game in Spelunky far, far easier to handle.

I have random luck with finding pistols in boxes, however those are few and far between.  Having enough gold to purchase one in the randomly-generated weapons shops is also often difficult, as shotguns are quite expensive (though I have been able to purchase the random pistol).

I am curious if there is any surefire method for increasing my ability to acquire a weapon without murdering the shopkeeper, as dealing with his relatives at each successive exit becomes a pain, and often leads to my brutal, bloody death at the hands of a shotgun blast.

Comment: I don't think the shopkeeps are innocent. If you try any funny business, they'll go after ya!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides finding one randomly or from a shopkeeper, you can find shotguns beneath graves labeled "ASH" (a reference to the Evil Dead movies) on Restless Dead type Jungle levels. This can be as early as the fifth level, not sure what your criteria for "early" is.

Comment: Honestly was hoping for 'the first few' levels, as Jungle is kind of a pain without the nice clearing blast of the shotgun

Comment: Spelunky isn't in the habit of making things easy for you!

Comment: I've noticed!  Reminds me quite a bit of Nethack in that regard

Answer (score 0):

You can also get them by going to a dice rolling place (i don't know what their actual name is) and get them, though that is more rare. Sometimes they are in crates though too.